# I lost my option to use a key that allows me to speak my text or emails

Tags: keyboard

I have a samsung galaxy s5 - my email and text keyboard has dropped the key that allows me to speak my text and I can't find a way to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Galaxy S5, but one possibility is that you have somehow disabled the voice input method, typically Google voice typing is provided as the default.

Try going to Settings > Language & input, and check whether the Google voice typing input method is disabled and if it is, enable it and try again.